# HTML object Element makes .svg image not fit?

Tags: html, svg

I've placed some .svg code in a specific HTML file.
I've also got an object tag in my actual website HTML file as seen below:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml"class="img-responsive navbar-center" data="LogoAnimated.html" height="173px" width="192px"></object>
```

When I run this code it puts a scrollbar next to my .svg image. I've tried to remove it with overflow: hidden, but it's still there.

Before I had my specific HTML file with the .svg code inside of it I had the .svg code inside my actual website HTML file. I didn't have to link a different HTML file to my actual HTML file, but instead I just had a `<svg></svg>` element in my HTML with all the .svg code inside of it.
Now that I have the .svg code in a different HTML file and I'm using the `<object>` element to link it it gives me the scrollbar, even though it didn't give me the scrollbar when I had my .svg code in my actual HTML file.

I don't want to place my .svg code in my actual HTML file, because It's a lot of code, and I don't want it to look messy.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you show a piece of example code that demonstrates the issue? A quick and dirty text reveals no scrollbars, so I'm probably doing it differently than you.

Comment: Why do you use an object to display an image?

Comment: By the way, you have errors in your HTML. Missing space before the `class` attribute, `px` units in the `width` and `height` attributes, and of course the SVG file itself, which @jcaron mentions.

Comment: @LGSon Using an object has the advantage of being able to put fallback content inside, e.g. a png file, for browsers that don't support SVG images.

Comment: @MrLister Well that could be solved like this as well: `<img src="image.svg" onerror="this.src='image.png'">` and keeping images as images in the html structure

Comment: @LGSon Well, I don't know the OP's reasoning, but my thoughts would be that a solution which doesn't require JavaScript might be preferable over one that does.

Comment: @MrLister Agree fully with that, though as OP didn't add in whats necessary for the `object` fallback, I asked to raise the awareness of it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your SVG code in an HTML file. Put it in an SVG file, with a .svg extension, and with only actual SVG inside it.